# TFS throws an TeamFoundationServerInvalidResponseException when trying to Authenticate

Tags: c#, .net, tfs

I'am checking out some files from TFS programatically and before each call to checkout i check whether i'am authenticated or not. Some of the files are checked out correctly but on one file the Authenticate() methods fails with the following exception:

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServerInvalidResponseException: Wenden Sie sich an den Administrator. Fehler bei der Anforderung an den Server.
Technische Informationen (für Administrator):
  HTTP-Code 200: OK
   bei Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.ReadMessage(HttpWebResponse webResponse, WebException webException, Stream responseStream, Boolean& closeResponse)
   bei Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.ReadResponse(HttpWebResponse webResponse, WebException webException)
   bei Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.IsAuthenticationChallenge(TfsMessage requestMessage, HttpWebResponse webResponse, WebException webException, TfsMessage& responseMessage)
   bei Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.SendRequest()
   bei Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpRequestChannel.Request(TfsMessage message, TimeSpan timeout)
   bei Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.Invoke(TfsClientOperation operation, Object[] parameters, TimeSpan timeout, Object[]& outputs)
   bei Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.LocationWebService.Connect(Int32 connectOptions, Int32 lastChangeId, Int32 features)
   bei Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.FrameworkServerDataProvider.Connect(ConnectOptions connectOptions)
   bei Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.EnsureProviderConnected()
```

Does anyone have an idea, why i'am getting this `InvalidResponse` here?
I'am using the latest TFS Client Assemblies via NuGet.
The authentication is basically done like this:

```
m_tfsServer = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(serverUri), new TfsClientCredentials());
if(!m_tfsServer.HasAuthenticated)
    m_tfsServer.Authenticate();
```

Comment: how are you passing serveruri?

Comment: ServerUri is actually passed like "http://myserver/tfs"

Comment: Does this exception always only occurs when check authentication before that file?  Does that file belong to the same team project collection with other files?

Comment: Yes i'am allways trying to authenticate with the check from above before checking out the file. All the files belongs to the same team project.

Answer (score 2):

usually I do it in following way:

```
             string STRuri=@"http://myserver/teamservercollection"
             TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(STRuri));                 
             VersionControlServer vcs = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
             Workspace workspace = vcs.GetWorkspace(System.Environment.MachineName, vcs.AuthenticatedUser);
```